# C# Any direct function converts HHMMSS to miliseonds format

Tags: c#

Wondering if there is any function in C# that directly converts Real time in Format HHMMSS to Miliseconds format. For eg: 24:60:60 the miliseconds should be 90060000.
I have read multiple posts but none helped me give a solution, that converts directly

I just have written this piece of code written,

```
string formatted = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");
```

Comment: Take a look at `TimeSpan` class.  Also are you starting with a `DateTime` or with a `string`?  Because `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds * 1000` would seem to be what you want.

Comment: You do not need DateTime if you do not care about the date.
 See the methods available on [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370(v=vs.110).aspx), in particular Parse, ToString, and TotalMilliseconds.

Comment: I will be starting with date time, I also have a need to print that in string format of "HHmmss" as well as milisecond wquivalent of "HHmmss" TimeSpan class gives a diff between two time values, that will not help me.

Comment: @NewLearner There is no such a built in method that will give you results that you are expecting, try googling it, figure out what is DateTime.ParseExact, also take a look at TimeSpan.TotalMiliseconds etc

Comment: @NewLearner all you're doing is getting the time of day which is the difference between the `DateTime` at the beginning of the day and the current `DateTime`.  `DateTime.TimeOfDay` is a `TimeSpan` and `TimeSpan` has properties to get the amount of time in different units.

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` class has a `TimeOfDay` property that returns a `TimeSpan` that represents the amount of time since the beginning of the day.  With that you can get the time in milliseconds

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string formatted = now.ToString("HHmmss");
int milliseconds = (int)now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds * 1000;
```

I'm getting the total seconds and casting to `int` and multiplying by 1000 because your format is truncating any precision beyond seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for [TimeSpan.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You can use it to parse your string and display the number of milliseconds like this:

```
string formatted = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");
TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.ParseExact(
    formatted, "hhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.Write(interval.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime x = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, x.Hour, x.Minute, x.Second);
Console.WriteLine(span.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Thanks this works!! As am a newbie, your response definitely helps me get through